# What tool to send push notification to android phone?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I need to test the `C2DM service`. I have already implemented the service in my Android app. Before starting coding the `third party server` which gonna send the `notifications` i would like to test my app.

Is there any tool working on `Windows` (preferably with an UI) which allow me to enter the registration_id of my phone , the account used into C2DM and a message.

I'm looking for a `jar` or an `exe` , don't bother to propose `php` or any `web server` based script , i can't install any server or interpreter on the computer which have access to internet :'( .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally build my own command line tool based on [this article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html#tutorial_serverapp) . Probably faster than keep searching a ready to use tool.

Answer (score 4):

C2DM is now depricated. 
Use Android GCM http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work to run as the server in VB http://www.androidsnippets.com/vbnet-server-side-code-to-send-c2dm-messages

Seems to work nicely, hopefully that's the direction you were talking about.